# What are the better (pseudo) random number generator than the LCG for lottery scheduler?

Tags: c, random, scheduling, scheduler

I want to design a lottery scheduler and I need to have a very good (pseudo) random  number generator similar to LCG but I was wondering if there are other better choice out there or not? I am specifically looking for random generators written in C.

LCG code:

```
unsigned long lcg_rand(unsigned long a)
{
  return (a * 279470273UL) % 4294967291UL;
}
```

Also I would like to know if `srand()` can be used for this purpose or is not highly accurate?

Comment: Is there a reason you chose these parameters for your LCG? The modulus is rather unusual and unless you chose it for a specific reason it's likely to give you unwanted bias.

Answer (score 7):

If you need simple but decent quality, I would use the upper 32 (or fewer) bits of a 64-bit LCG, possibly with a tempering function applied to the output. When doing this, I've copied the tempering function used in [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister). I would not recommend actually using Mersenne Twister, as it has a lot more complexity and internal state than other PRNGs without significantly better qualities.

Here is some sample code:

```
static uint32_t temper(uint32_t x)
{
    x ^= x>>11;
    x ^= x<<7 & 0x9D2C5680;
    x ^= x<<15 & 0xEFC60000;
    x ^= x>>18;
    return x;
}
uint32_t lcg64_temper(uint64_t *seed)
{
    *seed = 6364136223846793005ULL * *seed + 1;
    return temper(*seed >> 32);
}
```

Comment: Should your prototype for ***uint32_t*** `lcg64_temper(uint64_t *seed)` be ***uint64_t*** `lcg64_temper(uint64_t *seed)` and then cast _*seed_:  `return temper((uint32_t)(*seed) >> 32);` ? Or was this intentionally coded _to use the upper 32 (or fewer) bits of a 64-bit LCG_ as you described above?

Answer (score 2):

[Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) would be one option. Another option is [Subtract with carry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtract_with_carry)

Comment: +1 for relevance, but for future answers, consider ***[these guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)***.  This could have been offered as a comment just as easily.

Answer (score 1):

most implementations of the C  `rand()` function use variations of ***[LGC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)***.  `rand()`, like any computerized random generator is not truly random, it is only pseudo random.  Using `srand()` can *improve* randomness, but not make it perfect.  It depends on how varied and random the seed used in `srand()` is.  For example if you called `rand()` n times using the same identical seed in `srand()`, the results would be the same.   But if you called `srand(clock())` each time (and the elapsed time between calls was greater than the period of ticks in `clock()`), then you would have an improved random generator.

Here is a simple code example, where both `clock()` and a support function, *NotRecentlyUsed()* (for small samples of *min* and *max*) are used:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

#define _UNIQUE_

int randomGenerator(int min, int max);
int NotUsedRecently (int number);

int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        printf("%d,\t", randomGenerator(0, 20));
            if(i%20 == 0) printf("\n");
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;   
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//generates pseudo random numbers between min and max
//If it is desired to use this without a guarantee of uniqueness
//for a specified span of values, un-define _UNIQUE_
//
int randomGenerator(int min, int max)
{
    int random, trying;

    trying = 1;         
    while(trying)
    {
        srand(clock());
        random = (rand()/32767.0)*(max+1);
        ((random >= min)
#ifdef _UNIQUE_
            && NotUsedRecently(random) 
#endif
            ) ? (trying = 0) : (trying = 1);
    }

    return random;
}

//This function is used to guarantee that a span of n generated values
//will not be the same. To adjust the span, change the index in 
//static int recent[n];  Note: it is required that n < (max-min)
//otherwise an infinite loop will occur
int NotUsedRecently (int number)
{
    static int recent[20];//Use No greater value for index than max - min
    int i,j;
    int notUsed = 1;

    for(i=0;i<(sizeof(recent)/sizeof(recent[0]));i++)  (number != recent[i]) ? (notUsed==notUsed) : (notUsed=0, i=(sizeof(recent)/sizeof(recent[0])));
    if(notUsed) 
    {
        for(j=(sizeof(recent)/sizeof(recent[0]));j>1;j--)
        {
            recent[j-1] = recent[j-2];
        }
        recent[j-1] = number;
    }
    return notUsed;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make a lot of sense. It might work on your machine but the output doesn't appear correct using [gcc on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/E39tcQ)

Comment: This code almost works on VS2012 because your magic number `32767.0` matches the MS runtime `RAND_MAX` but it produces _random_ numbers in ascending order (not very random in my opinion). In addition, if you call `randomGenerator(0, 20)` the code gets stuck in an infinite loop due to that `NotUsedRecently()` stuff. Finally, SO has multiple questions and answers showing why calling `srand()` every time you call `rand()` is a poor idea.

Comment: @Blastfurnace - The only thing you have said that I can confirm is that yes 32767 is #defined as RAND_MAX in some environments.  I used the raw integer here in case an environment did  not have that #define.  As for your claim that it produces _random numbers in ascending order_, I cannot reproduce that. I have used this code successfully for over 10 years (with variations to the arguments for different applications) and it has worked flawlessly.  My implementations of this same code have been validated in applications where randomness is a requirement. As for _NotUsedRecently_,

Comment: it has two purposes: 1) Primarily to guarantee that no two numbers are the same within a specified span of generated values.  2) to provide a small delay such that srand(clock()) has time to tick before the next _recent[n]_ generations have occurred.  It is important to adjust the index value in _recent[n]_ to support the range of numbers you will accept in _min_ and _max_, i.e. if min and max are set to 0 and 20, but you are requiring 64 unique random numbers, it will indeed be an infinite loop.   Not otherwise.  I will comment the source to make that clear.

Comment: So you're using `rand` as a hash function of the current time? You throw away any state that `rand` saves between calls and use a clock that increases at a steady rate as your source of entropy. The whole thing looks very suspect but you do whatever you think is right.