# Fast C random boolean generator

Tags: c, performance, random, boolean

I'm interested in generating fast random booleans (or equivalently a Bernoulli(0.5) random variable) in C. Of course if one has a fast random generator with a decent statistical behaviour the problem "sample a random Bernoulli(0.5)" is easily solved: sample `x` uniformly in (0,1) and return `1` if `x<0.5`, `0` otherwise.

Suppose speed is the most important thing, now I have two questions/considerations:

1. Many random doubles generators first generate an integer `m` uniformly in a certain range `[0,M]` and then simply return the division `m/M`. Wouldn't it be faster just to check whether `m < M/2` (here `M/2` is fixed, so we are saving one division)

   2. Is there any faster way to do it? At the end, we're asking for way less statistical properties here: we're maybe still interested in a long period but, for example, we don't care about the uniformity of the distribution (as long as roughly 50% of the values are in the first half of the range).

Comment: is your question how to write it or where to find something like this?

Comment: For random booleans, `clock()&1` could suffice.

Comment: (1) You can probably just profile and compare.  (2) Assuming a perfect input RNG, you can extract 32 (or whatever your word size is) random booleans from each random integer.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie wouldn't `clock()&1` be ok just for one random number? If I call it 20K times in a row, wouldn't it return very correlated randoms?

Comment: @KamiKaze I'm happy to write it or find it, as soon as it works fine :)

Comment: Just use the *random* function that is available on your platform (`rand`, `random`, `arc4random`, etc.) and keep one bit from the returned value.

Comment: How *fast* do you need it? Sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: generate an unsigned 64 bit integer and use the bits as boolean values. Thats like generating 64 boolean values in 1 go.

Comment: or just read from `/dev/urandom` 2.5KB if you want 20K random boolean values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracting say the last bit of a random number can wreak havoc as linear congruential generators can alternate between odd and even numbers<sup>1</sup>. A scheme like `clock() & 1` would also have ghastly correlation plains.

---

Consider a solution based on the quick and dirty generator of Donald Kunth: for `uint32_t I`, sequence

```
I = 1664525 * I + 1013904223;
```

and `2 * I < I` is the conditional yielding the Boolean drawing. Here I'm relying on the wrap-around behaviour of `I` which should occur half the time, and a potentially expensive division is avoided.

Testing `I <= 0x7FFFFFFF` is less flashy and might be faster still, but the hardcoding of the midpoint is not entirely satisfactory.

---

<sup>1</sup> The generator I present here does.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm interested in generating fast random booleans

Using a [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) can be fast, yet since OP's needs only a `bool` result, consider extracting only 1 bit at a time from a reasonable generator and save the rest for later. [@Akshay L Aradhya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255406/fast-c-random-boolean-generator/50258258?noredirect=1#comment87529894_50255406)

Example based on [@R..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19735285/2410359) and [@R..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19083740/2410359) code.

```
extern uint32_t lcg64_temper(uint64_t *seed); // see R.. code

static uint64_t gseed; //  Initialize this in some fashion.
static unsigned gcount = 0;

bool rand_bool(void) {
  static uint32_t rbits;
  if (gcount == 0) {
    gcount = 32;  // I'd consider using 31 here, just to cope with some LCG weaknesses.
    rbits = lcg64_temper(&gseed);  
  }
  gcount--;
  bool b = rbits & 1;
  rbits >>= 1;
  return b;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this will work out faster than my solution in common use cases?

Comment: @Bathsheba Many unknowns, particularly the cost of a wide integer multiplication.  The higher that cost, the more profitable to extract 1 bit and save the rest.  The _fuzzy_ part is how [low a quality random number](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25) generator can we go to meet OP's need of randomness vs. speed?

Comment: Upped all the same.