# C11 alternative to rand?

Tags: c, random, c11

As we know, C++11 got some improvements to random with new additions to `<random>` as well as some proposals which aim to improve it further. But it seems like C11 has no improvements whatsoever.

Is there a way to avoid using `rand()` in C11?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a function using some (normally simple) *PRNG* implementation. You can always "avoid" it and instead provide your own implementation, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083566) for some alternatives.

BTW, you should think about your intended application. Most `rand()` implementations will do just fine for e.g. games, so there's no need to roll out your own. On the other end of the scale, you probably *never* want to use a *PRNG* **at all** for some tasks in cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

There is none, unfortunately. The simplest solution is using the underlying PRNG provided by your system, `/dev/urandom` for *Unix systems and the [CryptoApi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI) under Windows.

Comment: No, if you are on a POSIX system, which Linux is, you have a lot of alternatives. In particular there is the `rand48` family of PRG, that are not too bad.